# Saving Pool with categorical data (Python package)

Tags: catboost

I have a dataset primarily composed of categorical features. To support our ML workflow, including hyperparameter tuning, I'd like to save the quantized Pools. It appears this is not supported (see below). What is the best practice approach to snapshotting Pools for reuse when they contain categorical features?

```
In [8]: train_pool.quantize() 
   ...: train_pool.save("train_pool.bin")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
uncaught exception:
    address -> 0x11000a800
    what() -> "catboost/libs/quantized_pool/serialization.cpp:960: Saving quantization results is supported only for numerical features"
    type -> TCatBoostException
Aborted
```

I'm using Catboost 0.17.4.